# How to find the shortest even length cycle in a bipartite graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

If you have n vertices and m edges, how would you find the shortest cycle of a bipartite graph in O(n^2) time? To do it in O(nm) time, it is simply a BFS on every single vertex. I do not understand how you can do it just by going over every single vertex. I know you would have to stop at non-tree edges to do so, but how would you use this type of technique to guarantee this runtime and find the shortest cycle? Could anyone give me some sort of advice or help?

Comment: Can you credit the source where you originally encountered this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a BFS visit from each vertex of the graph. Stop each visit as soon as you encounter a cycle. To be more precise, the BFS visit classifies vertices as "visited", "discovered" (but not already visited), and "unknown". We stop the visit whenever we are visiting a vertex $v$ that has an edge towards a vertex that was already in the "discovered" state. In this way the BFS visit will examine only $O(n)$ vertices/edges. Return the shortest discovered cycle.

To see that this algorithm must work, let $2k$ be the length of the shortest cycle $C$, let $s$ be an arbitrary vertex in $C$, call $u$ and $v$ the two vertices at distance $k-1$ from $s$ in $C$, and let $w$ be the unique vertex at distance $k$ from $s$ in $C$.

Consider the BFS visit from $s$ and notice that if a cycle is encountered while visiting a vertex at level $\ell$ of the BFS tree, then its length is $2\ell+2$.

No cycle can be encountered while visiting levels $0$ though $k-2$ (as otherwise the shortest cycle would have length at most $2k-2$). Moreover, a cycle must be encountered at level $k-1$. This is obvious if the visit was halted before visiting both $u$ and $v$, therefore suppose that both $u$ and $v$ are visited, in this order (w.l.o.g.).
When $u$ was visited, the state of $w$ changed from "unknown" to "discovered" (since $(u,w)$ is an edge of the graph). When $v$ was visited, the edge $(v,w)$ was encountered, and the visit was stopped since $w$ was already in the "discovered" state.